# EsHadoopException: Could not write all entries for bulk operation Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-streaming

I want to traverse the stream of data, run a query on it and return the results which should be written into ElasticSearch. I tried to use mapPartitions method for creation of the connection to the database, however, I get such an error, which indicates that partition returns None to the rdd  (I guess, some action should be added after the transformations):

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopException: Could not write all entries for bulk operation [10/10]. Error sample (first [5] error messages)
```

What can be changed in the code to get the data into rdd and send it to ElasticSearch without any troubles?

Alos, I had a variant of the solution for this problem with flatMap in foreachRDD, however, I create a connection to the database on each rdd, which is not effective in terms of performance.

This is the code for streaming data processing:

```
wordsArrays.foreachRDD(rdd => {

        rdd.mapPartitions { part => {
          val neo4jConfig = neo4jConfigurations.getNeo4jConfig(args(1))
          part.map(
            data => {

              val recommendations = execNeo4jSearchQuery(neo4jConfig, data)
              val calendarTime = Calendar.getInstance.getTime
              val recommendationsMap = convertDataToMap(recommendations, calendarTime)

              recommendationsMap

            })
        }
        }
    }.saveToEs("rdd-timed/output")
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to convert the iterator directly into the Array, although it holds multiple rows of my records. That is why ElasticSEarch was not able to map this collection of records to the defined single record schema.
Here is the code that works properly:

```
   wordsArrays.foreachRDD(rdd => {

      rdd.mapPartitions { partition => {
            val neo4jConfig = neo4jConfigurations.getNeo4jConfig(args(1))

            val result = partition.map( data => {

              val recommendations = execNeo4jSearchQuery(neo4jConfig, data)
              val calendarTime = Calendar.getInstance.getTime
              convertDataToMap(recommendations, calendarTime)

          }).toList.flatten
          result.iterator
        }
      }.saveToEs("rdd-timed/output")
    })
```